# Instant App not available for testing

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I’m working to add instant app feature to an existing application but I can’t manage to test the instant app via Internal Test or Alpha Test.

For testing purpose I created a completely new application on Google Play Console and compiled the “**hello-java**” sample in Git repository 
[Google samples:- android-instant-apps](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps) , changing digital asset links.

I can correctly run the instant app via Android Studio on a real device.

On Google Play Console I uploaded an installed app APK in “**Internal Test**” and added a group of tester. It works correctly, I can see and download the installed app.

Then I uploaded an instant app APK in “Internal Test” but:

- test method dropdown is grayed out
- when I open the URL provided by the Google Play Console: [https://play.google.com/apps/instantapptesting/*id*](https://play.google.com/apps/instantapptesting/_id_) I get redirected to https://play.google.com/apps/internaltest/_package_name_ and I see the message “App not available for this account”

I tried the same process on Alpha channel but:

- test method dropdown is grayed out
- when I open the URL provided by the Google Play Console: [https://play.google.com/apps/instantapptesting/*id*](https://play.google.com/apps/instantapptesting/_id_) I get redirected to https://play.google.com/apps/testing/_package_name_ and I see the page of the testing program
- when I open App’s page on Google Play Store I don’t see “Try now” button

What am I missing?

Thank you

P.S.
The device I’m testing on has “Instant Apps” enabled (I tried other Instant App already on Play Store)

Answer (score 0):

FWIW I just took a look at setup I have here for an instant app I have deployed...under "Android Instant Apps" I click Manage/Manage testers for particular channel.  I had set this up a while back but I also do see that "Choose a testing method" is now greyed out as well for me.  I'm also seeing following warning which I suspect might be related to this:

> Changes to your Instant App's testing tracks
>
> You're instant app's pre-release and development tracks will soon be merged into your
>   installed app's alpha and internal test tracks respectively. 
>   IMPORTANT: Your installed app's alpha and internal test testers are
>   now your instant app's pre-release and development testers
>   respectively. You will only be able to edit and manage your instant
>   app's testers through your installed app's testing tracks. Your
>   instant app testers will soon be removed. Any testers for your instant
>   app can only be managed through your installed app's testing tracks.Your instant app's

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing this warning too but I don't understand why the dropdown is still there if the installed app's testers are already being used as instant app's testers. Moreover if I click the link at the bottom of the warning to configure the installed app's testers I get an error (736569003). Weird!

Comment: That link is probably supposed to go to `Release management > App releases > Internal test` From there, you can edit your test users. They've left remnants of the previous interface so people will be less confused? (but I guess that's not the case)